# How to set the multiple flags in QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt

From here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-windowflags-example.html

```
 if (flags & Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
     text += "\n| Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint";
 if (flags & Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint)
     text += "\n| Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint";
 if (flags & Qt::FramelessWindowHint)
     text += "\n| Qt::FramelessWindowHint";
 if (flags & Qt::WindowTitleHint)
     text += "\n| Qt::WindowTitleHint";
 if (flags & Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint)
     text += "\n| Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint";
 if (flags & Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
     text += "\n| Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint";
 if (flags & Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint)
     text += "\n| Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint";
 if (flags & Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint)
     text += "\n| Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint";
 if (flags & Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint)
     text += "\n| Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint";
 if (flags & Qt::WindowShadeButtonHint)
     text += "\n| Qt::WindowShadeButtonHint";
 if (flags & Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint)
     text += "\n| Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint";
 if (flags & Qt::CustomizeWindowHint)
     text += "\n| Qt::CustomizeWindowHint";
```

But when I do this:

```
Qt :: WindowFlags flags = 0;

flags = flags | Qt :: WindowStaysOnTopHint;
flags = flags & Qt :: WindowMinimizeButtonHint;
window->setWindowFlags (flags);
```

The first flag gets overwritten. What is the way to set more than one flags at the same time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
window->setWindowFlags (Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint );
```

For your information:

Window Flags are stored as *OR combinations* of the flags inside an object of the type `QFlags<WindowType>` where WindowType is an enum.

When storing the flags you combine their values using the bitwise *OR operator*.

For further information see the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-windowflags-example.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try with :

```
Qt :: WindowFlags flags = 0;

flags = flags | Qt :: WindowStaysOnTopHint;
flags = flags | Qt :: WindowMinimizeButtonHint;
window->setWindowFlags (flags);
```

Comment: any special reasons for removing the explanation?